# equivalent description of "respectively"

Tags: notation, terminology

I want to define two notions; can we use the notation () to represent "respectively"?

For example:  does the statement "A set has (weak) property C if"  have the same meaning as "A has (respectively, weak) property C if"?

Comment: Frankly, that's a bit confusing. Does it really hurt to make two statements?

Comment: So the text in the () does represent "respectively"?

Comment: Did you mean "(respectively, weak property) C"?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner, yes, can we use the notation (weak) to represent (respectively,weak)property c

Comment: I suppose we could

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it does. For instance, a set $S$ is strongly (resp. weakly) [property] if $S$ satisfies [something] (resp. [something else]).

Or you can drop "resp." entirely, e.g. $f_n$ is said to converge to $f$ strongly (weakly) if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly (pointwise). You can replace the adverb with an adjective as well, e.g. $g_n$ has the strong (weak) boundedness property on $X$ if $g_n$ is uniformly (pointwise) bounded.

I only write this if the strong property 'obviously' implies the weak property, but usually I interpret a sentence like this as saying if I were to replace the word preceding each bracket with the bracketed word then I have another assertion.

Comment: But the "strongly" and "weakly"are different notations. Is it common to use the "(A) something" to denote (respectibely,A) somsething ?

Comment: Does there exist equivalent descripition if avoid using the "respectively," too many times.

Comment: Not sure what you mean on the first comment. If you mean "Let $A, B \subset X$ where $A$ (resp. $B$) is open (resp. closed) then sure that's fine IMO. I would add "resp." in this case as it might look like $A$ ($B$) is some sort of operation. To answer your second question, you don't have to add resp. after each, you can also add it at the end. For instance, "where $A$ and $B$ are $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets respectively.